# error with add button in jquery/js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

when i run my script i have an error problem. i want to  add the add cart from radio buttons(3 buttons).

```
 $(document).ready(function(){ 
     $(".cart :input[name='rmr']").add(".cart :input[name='rmr']").click(function() {
         var checked = $(".cart :input[name=rmr]:checked");
         updatePayment(this.value);
         if (checked.length > 0) // make sure one is checked
              {
                 $("#finalamount").html( $("#totalamount").val() * checked.val() );
             }
         });
   });


function updatePayment(val) {
   $("<p/>").html("updatePayment(" + val + ")").appendTo(document.body);
 }
```

iam not sure with it. i have the confusion with add radio buttons.how could i do.
 plz help me..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is wrong, try such code instead:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
     $(".cart :input[name='rmr']").click(function() {
         updatePayment($(this).val());
         if (!!$(this).attr("checked") == true) {
             $("#finalamount").html( parseInt($("#totalamount").val(), 10) * parseInt($(this).val(), 10));
         }
     });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Please provide your HTML-Code.

And why do you do

```
$(".cart :input[name='rmr']").add(".cart :input[name='rmr']")
```

You select an input and then try to add the same input?